# how to make Nginx forward https traffic to upstream as a https proxy server?

Tags: nginx, proxy, load-balancing, tor

Here I want to setup a tor cluster with a nginx as load balancer to provide HA tor service. I choose "https://github.com/reiz/nginx_proxy" the nginx module to provide https_proxy feature. It works well with the https connections. but didn't forward the https traffic to upstream.

What happened:

Case 1:

When I run the cmd below, it will return a random ip from upstream tor services, it works well with http traffic.

```
curl -x localhost:8090 http://api.ipify.org
```

Case 2:

It failed with the https traffic, what I can see from access log is

```
"CONNECT api.ipify.org:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 6176 "-" "curl/7.54.0" "-"
```

Yes, as a https proxy, nginx works, but failed to forward the https traffic to Tor upstream. The command below always return the same ip, the current ip of my pc.

```
curl -x localhost:8090 https://api.ipify.org
```

So, what I want is, how to make the nginx forward https traffic to upstream ?

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  auto;
daemon off;

events {}


http {

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

default.conf

```
upstream torProxy {
    server tor-cluster_tor_1:8118 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server tor-cluster_tor_2:8118 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server tor-cluster_tor_3:8118 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server tor-cluster_tor_4:8118 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server tor-cluster_tor_5:8118 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server tor-cluster_tor_6:8118 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server tor-cluster_tor_7:8118 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server tor-cluster_tor_8:8118 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server tor-cluster_tor_9:8118 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server tor-cluster_tor_10:8118 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}

server {
    listen      8090;
    proxy_connect;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://torProxy;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Authorization "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nginx's [stream module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html). [Here](https://serversforhackers.com/tcp-load-balancing-with-nginx-ssl-pass-thru) is a good article to get you started.